# Halo 4 Spartan Ops Series/Episodes release schedule?

Tags: halo-4

What is the release schedule for Series 1 of Spartan Ops? I've heard there might be a break over christmas, is this true amd why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spartan Ops, Series 1 contains 10 "Episodes" in total, and each episode contains 5 "chapters" for a total of 50 total playable missions.

- Episode 1, released with Halo: 4, November 5th.
- Episode 2, released the following Monday, November 12th
- Episode 3, released the Monday after, November 19th
- Episode 4, released the Monday after that, November 26th
- Episode 5, released Monday, December 3rd.

December 10th, when Episode 6 should be relased, the Crimson Map Pack gets released and the Halo Infinity Challenge begins. Spartan Ops will go on a break until 21st Jan 2013 where episodes 6-10 will be relased (dates will likely be 21st Jan, 28th Jan, 4th Feb, 11th Feb and 18th Feb).

It is also unknown if further series will be released but it is likely that it will happen as DLC while Halo 5 is under development.